# Scrollbar behavior

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Usually when long press the up/down key in the browser or in some other web page it will take a very small amount of time for the scrollbar to start scrolling down.

I search some js or css but not work.How can I remove the delay with js or css?

Comment: I guess the simplest would be to listen to the keyup and keydown events, if the keydown key it's the down/up arrow start scrolling by X amount until you see the keyup event.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.